# rails shopping cart gem paperclip integration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, shopping-cart

I am trying to find me a shopping cart gem or a howto guide to build a shopping cart that I can integrate into the paperclip gem for my ruby on rails application.  I tried using the nimbleshop but it screwed up my users database, I tried building my own but I think the instructions were missing something, http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Ruby-on-Rails/Shopping-Cart-Implementation/1/ .  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I use Cartman on a shopping site.

Check it out:
https://github.com/willcosgrove/cartman